# Summing data points over a variable range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2019

Personally, I'm facing this problem, but with an added dimension:

|  | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1,600 | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |
| Feb | 1,600 | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |
| March | 1,600 | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |
| April | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 | 1,890 |
| May | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| June | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| July | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| August | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| Sept | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| October | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| Nov | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |
| Dec | 1,780 | 1,860 | 1,890 |  |

I want to generate a sum, say, between two dates the user inputs on a separate sheet:

| Start Date | 01/10/2019 |
| --- | --- |
| End Date | 01/03/2021 |
| Total Amount | XX,XXX |

Which is the most efficient formula to use and automatically pick up the relevant reference(s) and getting the sum...without going VBA.

[image]

Comment: Since you/a user enters START & END DATE,, then have U ever thought about SUMIF or SUMPRODUCT !!  Both are efficient enough to find the SUM between 2 given Dates .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm still a beginner and still earning the breadth of Excel's functions. I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the "most efficient" (or easiest to follow) would be with Office 365:

```
=LET(x,DATE(INDEX(monthData[#Headers],1,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(monthData)-1,2)),SEQUENCE(12),1),
     y, INDEX(monthData,SEQUENCE(12), SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(monthData)-1,2)),
     SUM( (x>=Start)*(x<End)*y))
```

But Excel 2019 is lacking both `SEQUENCE` and `LET`, so try this equivalent:

```
=SUM((DATE(INDEX(monthData[#Headers],1,COLUMN($B$1:INDEX($1:$1,,COLUMNS(monthData)))),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,12)),1)>=Start)
*(DATE(INDEX(monthData[#Headers],1,COLUMN($B$1:INDEX($1:$1,,COLUMNS(monthData)))),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,12)),1)<End)
*INDEX(monthData,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,12)),COLUMN($B$1:INDEX($1:$1,,COLUMNS(monthData)))))
```

In both, I converted the Data into a **Table** named `monthData`, and also assumed only 12 rows as you show.

- create an array of dates formed by the month and year intersection that corresponds to your array of data.
- If a month is outside the range `start-end` then replace it with a zero(0), otherwise with a one(1).
- Multiply that array by the original array and `SUM` the result
- Note that my dates are MDY, and that the End month is excluded from the SUM. (easily changed if that's not what you want).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will check it out and give feedback. As for the end date, I'd prefer to include it.

Comment: @Andy I don't know how to do that.  For example, with an end date of `1-Mar-2021`, and a data table that only shows full months, I don't see any way to tell the amount from March 2021 to attribute to your end date (which represents the **entire** month, not just one day). If you can explain how you would do that, the process can probably be implemented.